# Getting Pogo Games to Work

Tags: openjdk

I have Ubuntu 11.10, and have tried and googled till my eyes want to bleed.  Javaws works on about 50% of apps on the machine in commercial sites.  Yahoo sports will work for instance, but not the games.  I have tried 3 browsers, firefox/chrome/opera with no luck on the plugin.  the oracle plugin is only v.6 and just crashes.  the openjdk sits forever or force closes my browser.  Right now I am having to run a virtualbox installed win7 to play pogo games with my wife (which is just sad).  Please if there is a clear way to make the plugin work with a recent machine?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In another [forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/38417) this same issue came up. The root of the problem stemmed from the computer being 64 bit but Pogo seemed to need a 32 bit JRE. The individual installed icedtea-gcjwebplugin and Pogo finally worked.